# How do you allow URI encoded characters in CodeIgniter URLs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am using [CodeIgniter 1.7.1](http://www.codeigniter.com). My permitted URI characters are set as such:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@&\-';
```

When I type a address like http://website.com/index.php/controller/method/test%21, the page does not load and gives me the error:

> Code igniter: An Error Was EncounteredThe URI you submitted has
>   disallowed characters.

I don't understand. `%20` (space) is allowed, but `%21` (exclamation mark) is not.

Comment: Do you have the exclamation point in the allowed characters list? I think the browser interprets %21 as !, so when CodeIgniter parses it, it sees "!", not "%21"

Comment: @Goldentoa11 do I have to add all possible punctuation in its raw form to the list? Should I just permit all characters to avoid having to write a huge list? The comments in this config file say "don't allow all characters unless you know what you're doing". So what security holes would be open if I permitted all characters?

Comment: As per your first question, I think that's what you'll have to do. As per your second question, if CI says not to do that, I'd follow what it says, unless you understand what is going on behind the scenes, which I don't. As per your third question, I don't know what sort of holes would be opened up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%21` parse into `!` in codeigniter. So codeigniter doesn't support this please ! into permitted uri config file:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@&\-!';
```

Comment: what about ( + ) in url

Comment: i try to addit like this and it give me disallowed characters in url `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:;,_^$-+';`

Comment: Where should the above line be added in CI 3?

Answer (score -1):

try escaping it with this, that should work

```
\\+
```