# codeigniter 1.7 Disallowed Key Characters cyrillic character

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have massage "Disallowed Key Characters" whit url like this:

```
/project/category/Португалски
```

if url containd only latin chars problem is gone.

Problem come after removing index.php.
For removing  i use  in

```
config.php :
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

and

```
.htacces
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

After this url's work fine exept this url's whit cyrillic chars.
I read many questions for this before me and try differend solutions like:

in core/input/ _clean_input_keys function i change

```
 if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
 to
 if ( !preg_match("/^[a-z0-9а-яА-Я~%:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
```

i tried other variant of this expresion but result is the same.
 in config.php i change:

```
 $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-';
 to
 $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-а-яА-Я';
 after this i tried 
 $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}0-9~%.:_\-';
```

result sill is same. Massage  "Disallowed Key Characters".
When i remove .htaccess rile and put again index.php in config all work whit cyrillic without problem.

**SOLVED** - 
I just change text in.htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now evriting is work fine :)

Comment: encode the string before sending it to url and decode it later

Comment: i tried this too. No success.

Comment: which one you used for encoding , try base64_encode() and base64_decode()

Comment: Hm... how your url with cyrilic chars looking in browser output (should be encoded, right?)? Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456574/how-do-you-allow-uri-encoded-characters-in-codeigniter-urls