# Codeigniter Uri segments are not printing special characters correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, utf8-decode

I have url [http://localhost/my_project/welcome/special_chars/äöü](http://localhost/my_project/welcome/special_chars/%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC)
Now I am trying to print last segment using 
echo utf8_decode($this->uri->segment(3));
I am not getting the original value but when I write print like
echo utf8_decode('äöü');
then I am getting proper value.

Answer (score 0):

I think its something to do with **permitted_uri_characters** setting in the config.
You need to add your special character in the config like

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@&\-!';
```

For more info please refer this link: [How do you allow URI encoded characters in CodeIgniter URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456574/how-do-you-allow-uri-encoded-characters-in-codeigniter-urls)

Comment: special characters are shown correctly in  in url http://localhost/my_project/welcome/special_chars/äöü
The problem when I try to print last segment of url then output is not shown correctly. For example
echo $this->uri->segment(3); //Here it should print äöü but it is not